# Check pasted text formatting using Javascript

Tags: javascript, copy-paste, fraud-prevention

So I'm trying to detect if some text was pasted from ChatGPT
I know about other AI tools that detect it by the language and structure, but it's not too hard to pass its tests.
**So I wanna add a second layer of security that will check the pasted text style before it being added to the text field.**
I tried hooking myself to the paste event, but I couldn't find a way to get the text's style info.
Anyone has any clue how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just found out I missed the correct type from clipboardData.getData.

Here's a working code -

```
//$0 is the HtmlElement that the text is being pasted into
function handlePaste(e) {
  var clipboardData, pastedData;

  // Stop data actually being pasted into div
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get pasted data via clipboard API
  clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  pastedData = clipboardData.getData('text/html');

  // Do whatever with pasteddata
  console.log(pastedData);
}

$0.addEventListener('paste', handlePaste);
```